# How to use an argument as the key in a mapping in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to map a key to a tuple in a method. The key is an argument of the method.  I was thinking of using a dictionary to do that. But the key in the dictionary has to be a constant, is it ok to use the method's argument as the key? If not, what data structure should I use to do that?

Comment: Do you want to create a [generic memoization function or decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize)?

Comment: Post a sample of your code ?...And why not use it as argument?..Did u try it or face any issues?

Comment: I am just not sure if an argument can be treated as a constant since the key should be a constant.

Comment: Short answer Yes! but if key is *hashable*

Comment: if the argument is of a constant (more precisely: hashable) type, such as tuple, int, string, etc., then it's not a problem. Note that the value of the argument (and thus the key in the dict) will not change if the variable that was passed as an argument is assigned a new value, in case that was your concern.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definition of a dictionary in the [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html):

> **dictionary**
>   An associative array, where arbitrary keys are mapped to values. **The keys can be any object with __hash__() and __eq__() methods.**
>   Called a hash in Perl.

You will understand that the proper term for a dictionary key is to be *hashable* (equivalent to constant), now what *hashable* means:

> **hashable**
>
> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a **hash**() method), and can be
>   compared to other objects (it needs an **eq**() method). Hashable
>   objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> **Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key** and a set member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.
>
> All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable, while no mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are. Objects which
>   are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default; they
>   all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their hash value is
>   derived from their id().

So, for instance:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for k,v in zip(range(5), 'TESTS'): #intergers are hashable
        d[k] = v
>>>
>>> d
{0: 'T', 1: 'E', 2: 'S', 3: 'T', 4: 'S'}
>>>
>>> l = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
>>> for k,v in zip(l, 'TESTS'):
        d[k] = v


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#610>", line 2, in <module>
    d[k] = v
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Finally, putting that into your test case:

```
>>> def make_dict(k_list, v_list):
        d = {}
        for k,v in zip(k_list, v_list):
            d[k] = v
        return d

>>> make_dict(range(5), 'TESTS')
{0: 'T', 1: 'E', 2: 'S', 3: 'T', 4: 'S'}
>>> 
>>> 
>>> l = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
>>> 
>>> make_dict(l, 'TESTS')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#607>", line 1, in <module>
    make_dict(l, 'TESTS')
  File "<pyshell#601>", line 4, in make_dict
    d[k] = v
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```